# RFECV Does not Indicate Top 5 Features as Expected

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, data-science, rfe

I'm following [these scikit-learn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV). My code is at the bottom for reference.

The docs example states `The following example shows how to retrieve the a-priori not known 5 informative features`, however when I run similar code I only get 1 or 2 features, depending on the estimator I use.

Further, I have manually explored these variables and I know that I can easily improve the adjusted r-squared by including other variables. So my question is two-fold:

1. What criteria is RFECV using to pick winners and losers?
2. In the docs example, is it only picking 5 because that happens to be the number of Rank 1 results?

My code:

```
deskewed = analysis.getDeskewedData()

kitchen_sink_formula = '''hirability ~
    + gender*favor_programming_career*favor_seeking_risk*industry
    + 1'''

kitchen_sink_model = sm.OLS.from_formula(kitchen_sink_formula, data=deskewed)

y = kitchen_sink_model.endog
X = kitchen_sink_model.exog

estimator = LinearRegression()

rfe_model =  RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5)
results = rfe_model.fit(X, y)

print(results.support_) # only 1 feature is TRUE
```

Comment: I see `model.coef_` is used, but I'm not sure how it's computed. ref: https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-feature-importance-with-python/

Comment: This makes me think that it's really just the coefficient sizes ie Beta values - this seems really unsound to me as a statistical approach because effect size should be weighted by significance to find importance https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. How did you fix it since 7 month ?